# Create internal exchange

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

Использую Nuget-пакет RabbitMQ.Client версии 6.2.2

Мне требуется подключится к amq.rabbitmq.event, созданному Event Exchange Plugin.
Не смог найти программного функционала для подключения с параметром internal = true.

Метод IModel.ExchangeDeclare не имеет перегрузок с параметром internal. Пробовал передать параметр с помощью arguments (это разные варианты, какие пробовал, думал вдруг там точная проверка на соответсвие текста имени настройки):

```
arguments = new Dictionary<string, object> { {"internal", true} };
arguments = new Dictionary<string, object> { {"internal", "true"} };
arguments = new Dictionary<string, object> { {"Internal", true} };
arguments = new Dictionary<string, object> { {"Internal", "true"} };
```

Однако все варианты создают Exchange именно с arguments, а мне нужен параметр internal.
Который есть, как мне удалось найти, в языке Go, и видно в интерфейсе в браузере (из соответствующего плагина)

Comment: Обязательно передавать именно 4 раза подряд, а не 3 и не 5?

Comment: Поправил вопрос, это как я пробовал передавать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как выяснилось в итоге по каким то причинам Nuget пакет RabbitMQ.Client не содержит методов для управления параметром Internal, в отличии от например языка Go, у которого такая перегрузка имеется.

Исходная цель была не колхозить с подключениями и сделать новое подключения в рамках ООП. Однако в связи с этой особенностью пришлось ставить проверку на наличие в конфиге этого параметра и пропускать вызов ExchangeDeclare при соответствующим флаге.

Видимо я неправильно понял принцип RabbitMQ, т.к. к Exchange в данном случае мне подключаться не надо, его создаст и с ним работает сам RabbitMQ (плагин, если точнее).

Осталось только недоумение зачем такая возможность другим языкам.